# How to approach this scenario of inserting records to database using JDBC java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Please see the class below

```
    public class WriteTable {

    private void readResults() {
        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
            readFinalResults();
            writeResults();
        }

    }

    private void readFinalResults() {
        for(int i=0; i<=100; i++) {
            writeFinalResults();
        }
    }

    private void writeResults() {
        //prepared statements....
        //Insert query of table A
        //executeupdate
        //commit
    }

    private void writeFinalResults() {
        //prepared statements....
        //Insert query of table B
        //executeupdate
        //commit
    }
 }
```

Currently I have it this way. What's happening is when there is an error in the writeFinalResults() method it still goes on and executes writeResults() method. What I'm trying to do is write the content of an XML to a MySql server DB tables.

There are two tables I'm trying to write. I know I can do batch transaction. But since it's a big XML what if insert query fails half way through.

Do I have to use any data structure to store and loop through it while inserting?

Comment: A method whose name begins with 'get' but does not return anything and instead invokes something whose name begins with 'write'?  You must be out of your mind.

Comment: If it still goes on, it means that you're catchning the SQLException and ignoring it, pretending nothing bad happened. Just don't catch the exception. Let it propagate.

Comment: @MikeNakis : it was just an example.

Comment: With your own code you can do whatever you like.  But it is precisely when putting together an example for others to read that you have to try to ***make sense***.

Comment: @MikeNakis : I modified the example. I hope it makes sense now

Comment: Sorry, but it does not.  You now have a method whose name begins with 'read' and returns nothing, and instead invokes something whose name begins with 'write'.  This. Makes. No. Sense.